# Match the words present in a string. If a words repeats in the sentence them give a message "Match", else give a message "No match"

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm tyring to make program which takes a sentence as input and then splits the different words in it. Now it compares the words and if a word repeats then gives a message match otherwise it gives no match. But on executing the same no `MsgBox` is displayed.

This is the script that I have written:

```
Dim sent
Dim i
Dim j
Dim k
sent = "Its a good day but every day is a good day"
words = Array(Split(sent))
For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)-1
  For j = LBound(words)+1 To UBound(words)
    k = StrComp(words(i), words(j))
    If k=0 Then
      MsgBox ("Match")
    Else
      MsgBox ("No Match")
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: The issue is `word = words = Array(Split(sent))` line is wrong, `Split(...)` returns an `Array` so there is no need to nest it in another one using `Array(...)`, at the moment `UBound(words)` will return `0`. Change that line to `words = Split(sent)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `For` loop will never run because the `UBound(words)` will return `0`.

This is because the `Split()` function returns an `Array` so there is no need for the extra `Array()` call which ends up giving you a single element Array containing another Array.

The solution is to change

```
words = Array(Split(sent))
```

to

```
words = Split(sent)
```

That will fix your initial problem, but there are other issues with the code you will need to address before it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work....using the below code...Thanks a lot

    sent = "Its a good day but every day is a good day"
    msgbox ("OK")
    k = split (sent)
    msgbox ("Ok")
    For i = lbound(k) to ubound(k)-1
    For j = lbound(k)+1 to ubound(k)  
      If j > i Then
      h = strcomp ( k(i) , k(j) )
      msgbox( k(i) & K(j) )
      msgbox (h)
     End If
    Next
    next

Comment: @Sunny glad you got it working but you really should consider [Ekkehard.Horner's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42007074/692942) for a far simpler and cleaner mechanism.

Comment: Yip thanks Lankymart....yeahi couldn't get his apporach as I was not aware of the dictionary object. I learnt and tried it now. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

VBScript's tool for classifying/counting tokens of types/recognizing is the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx).

Demo:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a : a = Split("Its a good day but every day is a good day")
Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim w
For Each w In a
    d(w) = d(w) + 1
    If 1 < d(w) Then
       WScript.Echo "more than one " & w & " - could 'Exit For'"
    End If
Next
For Each w In d.Keys()
    WScript.Echo w, d(w)
Next
```

(look ma, no nested loops!)

output:

```
cscript 42004404.vbs
more than one day - could 'Exit For'
more than one a - could 'Exit For'
more than one good - could 'Exit For'
more than one day - could 'Exit For'
Its 1
a 2
good 2
day 3
but 1
every 1
is 1
```

Comment: Better solution definitely but it doesn't answer the initial question, I could provide a complete solution but I was explaining why they had the issue that they did.

Comment: thanks Ekkehard.Horner. I had to learn abouth the dictionary object in order to understand your method. But I did leanr something new so thanks a lot.